# How to select multiple columns (inclusive and exclusive) simultaneously?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a data frame that has 246 columns. Specifically, I would like to slice columns 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 and then also select columns 82 to 94, the latter ones being inclusive, all at the same time in one command. I have tried `.iloc` and `.ix`, but they return syntax errors.

```py
new_df = df.iloc[:, [1, 2 ,4, 5, 6, 82:94]]

new_df = df.iloc[:, [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 82:94]]
  File "<ipython-input-6-012945e7610d>", line 1
    new_df = df.iloc[:, [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 82:94]]
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Same is returned by `.ix` too. Is there any other way to do this other than specifying exclusive column indexes (that would be a long command)?

Comment: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]+list(range(82,95))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can not mix indexes and slicing like that. A simple workaround is to use `range`:

```
new_df = df.iloc[:, [1, 2 ,4, 5, 6, *range(82,94)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = df.iloc[:, [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, list(range(82,94))]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform select and slicing operations together you can use [numpy.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), which helps in concatenating n number of array slices along an axis.

```
new_df = df.iloc[:, numpy.r_[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 82:94]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought pandas was missing a dedicated command for this.